# Get firestore collection in descending order of ids

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get a collection of documents in descending order of their ids. How do I get that?
What should I put in place of ?? to make that happen?

```
firebase.firestore().collection("users").orderBy(??, "desc").get();
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please also add the entire query that you intend to perform and the property on which you want the order.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for

```
firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentid()
```

Note that what this *actually* returns is *not* just the local documentID, but the *fully qualified path* all the way to root - *that* is actually what firestore indexes.

In your case, you'll only pull from collection "users", so effectively the documentid() will be "root/users/{documentid}"

(Yes, simple index lookups really do just append the collection to the documentID - it's part of Firestore's efficiency that there is "really" only one giant index)

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldPath